# Interrupted Time Series Analysis: Autocorrelation greater than 1?

Tags: time-series, arima, autocorrelation, segmented-regression

I am running an interrupted time series analysis. (Basically, I run a "before" and "after" linear regression, and measure the change in Constant/y-intercept.)

My objective: to measure the sudden drop in prescribing rate of a certain drug, which occurred at time *t*. I want to prove that case A is singificant, and cases B and C saw no change.

Everything I've read seems to indicate:

1. You adjust for seasonality, but you don't transform to remove trend from the data. (Because trend is usually relevant to your study.)
2. ARIMA(1,0,0), that is, a single order of autoregression, seems pretty standard.

**My question: when are higher levels of autoregression appropriate in ITS design?**

I'm using weekly data, so there's a fair amount of noise.  My data looks like this:
[image: Number of prescriptions per week]

and my Ljung-Box test tells me that there's still autocorrelation in my data.
[image]
(Significance <.05 means there's likely more autocorrelation in the data)

Should I use a higher order of autoregression? Importantly, will doing so inappropriately underestimate the sudden change at time *t*?

Comment: Your terminology could use a revision. Autocorrelation at lag greater than one is not the same as autocorrelation greater than 1. Also, in ARIMA models you have autoregressive order (not autocorrelation order).

Comment: Thank you for correcting my terminology, you're right. Does anyone have any thoughts on my problem, even if you don't have a complete answer?